terra::distance between point and polygon returns degrees instead of km
I have a simple polygon and a single point, both having the same crs with lonlat:
library(terra)

pol <- vect("POLYGON ((1 1, 3 1, 3 2, 4 3, 3 4, 2 4, 1 1))",crs="EPSG:4326")
pt <- vect(cbind(3.5,5),crs="EPSG:4326")


I want to calculate the distance between pt and the nearest point of pol which is point 5.
I used
terra::distance(pt,pol,unit="km")

but the results are in degrees instead of kilometers:
[1,] 1.118034

Calculating the length of the red line the long way, it turns out to be 123.7 km
perim(as.lines(vect(list(pt,as.points(pol)[5,]))))/1000

Although both x and y are SpatVectors with the same crs, distance returns degrees. Is this a bug or did I miss something?
I use version 1.7-78 of terra.

According to terra documentation The distance is always expressed in meter, except when the coordinate reference system is longitude/latitude AND one of the SpatVector(s) consists of lines or polygons. In that case the distance is in degrees, and thus not very useful (this will be fixed soon). Otherwise, results are more precise, sometimes much more precise, when using longitude/latitude rather than a planar coordinate reference system, as these distort distance
Using sf instead gives the right result
library(terra)

pol <- vect("POLYGON ((1 1, 3 1, 3 2, 4 3, 3 4, 2 4, 1 1))",crs="EPSG:4326")
pt <- vect(cbind(3.5,5),crs="EPSG:4326")

library(sf)

pol <- st_as_sf(pol)
pt <- st_as_sf(pt)

sf::st_distance(pol, pt)

Units: [m]
       [,1]
[1,] 124243

The difference with your value 123.7 can be explained by the way sf computes distance when in degrees (it uses spherical geometry)

Thanks, yes sf is a good source and I also use it. However, I was wondering why this happens with terra. I didn't know from documentation that the lonlat crs is an exception to the meters unit. Good to know!

Until the polygon terra::distance() issue is fixed, you can achieve this using a modified version of your code with terra::nearest(). By default, ellipsoidal geometry is used, which is more accurate in your use case.
library(terra)

# Return distance only in kilometres
nearest(pt, as.points(pol))$distance / 1000
# [1] 123.7222

# Return full nearest() object
nearest(pt, as.points(pol))
# class       : SpatVector 
#  geometry    : points 
#  dimensions  : 1, 7  (geometries, attributes)
#  extent      : 3, 3, 4, 4  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#  names       : from_id from_x from_y to_id  to_x  to_y  distance
#  type        :   <num>  <num>  <num> <num> <num> <num>     <num>
#  values      :       1    3.5      5     5     3     4 1.237e+05


Nice approach! Thanks!
